# PHP String replacement inside tags

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I'd like an output similar to this:

> <a title="icon-logo" href="http://localhost/projects/"><icon
>   class="icon"> </icon>About US</a>

But I am getting the following output:

> <a title="icon-logo" href="http://localhost/projects/">About
>   US<icon class="icon"> </icon > </a>

I need an icon tag before text.

My Code

```
 <?php
 $item_output = '<a href="http://localhost/projects/" title="icon-logo">About US</a>';
 $iconVar = "<icon class ='icon'> </icon>";
 $output = preg_replace('/(<a.*?>[^<]*?)</', '$1'.$iconVar . "<", $item_output);
 echo $output;
 ?>
```

Comment: ` $output = preg_replace('/(<a[^>]*>)([^<]*?)</', "$1$iconVar$2<", $item_output);`

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine